# How to count the number of occurrences of each word in a file?

Tags: ubuntu

I need a program to count the number of words along with number of occurrences of each word in a file.

(Most of the examples I found only count the total number of words.)

Comment: At least tell us what OS you're looking at.

Comment: Most of what code?

Comment: i'm using ubuntu os. looking for count of each word in a file. for example critic- 29
        the-52 like wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The free online service **[Wordcounter](http://www.wordcounter.com/)** ranks the most frequently used words in any given body of text. Use this to see what words you overuse or maybe just to find some keywords from a document.

Answer (score 17):

If using the command line (or a script) is fine, then there's a million options. Like by using Perl (for Windows you would need to install [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) or [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) with Perl):

```
perl -0777 -lape's/\s+/\n/g' FILENAME | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

[Explanation](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/computer/perltips.html):

- `perl -0777` causes Perl to operate on the entire file as if it were one line ("slurp mode").
- `'s/\s+/\n/g'` changes all whitespace into newlines, thus: the output of Perl is one word per line.
- The `sort` command sorts the words alphabetically.
- The `uniq` command eliminates duplicate words; with the `-c` option it also prints the number of occurrences.
- The second `sort` command, with the `-nr` option, sorts the resulting file numerically in descending order.

Comment: Why is perl needed here? What was wrong with cat FILENAME | sed s/' '/\\n/g ?

Comment: Because your example does not sort or give the number of occurrences of the word, while Arjan's does.

Comment: @Sirex, I guess you're right: `cat FILENAME | sed s/' '/\\n/g | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` might give the same results.

Comment: yea, i was implying that the rest of the command would still be needed. Down with perl one liners ! :)

Comment: @Sirex, I am no expert. But why is `sed` better than `perl`? (And maybe post this as an answer?)

Comment: @Sirex, are you going to post that as an answer, or what? ;-)

Comment: I guess. bah humbug !

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy. Just use the following command:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c | sort -r
```

Comment: Correct (though I guess `sort -r` needs the `-n` flag too), but only if each word is on a single line in the file itself. Indeed the question is not clear on that.

Answer (score 3):

From a Linux command line:

```
sed s/' '/\\n/g FILENAME | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

On Mac OS X, which uses the BSD version of `sed`, the `\n` needs [some magic](http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/):

```
sed 's/ /\'$'\n/g' FILENAME | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: I think stack exchange swallowed one of my backslashes. Try that.

Comment: Hmm, works for me !

Comment: Ah, the `\n` might need [some magic](http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/) on a Mac: `sed 's/ /\'$'\n/g' FILENAME | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` seems to do the trick in BSD's `sed` as used on OS X.

Comment: (Using 4 spaces to indent code makes life much easier!)

Answer (score 2):

Linux (Ubuntu) command line:

```
tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "[\n*]" < file1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Both MS Office and OpenOffice have this feature. Go to tools/word count.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Windows, you could use [Atlantis](http://www.atlantiswordprocessor.com/en/) word processor. It's got loads of great little features and touches including one to hi-light the overuse of words.